# display information, that is contained of an object, to a ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to display information about an object, concretely a customer. I mean name, last name, telephone number, adress, .... that is the result by a query on my database.

I want to display this on a ListView, so better if my activity inherit of a ListActivity because ListView is self-contained by default.

I do the next: I have a class called Customer that saves all information by the query (Cursor) that only return one record(customer) and I don't know how to pass this object ,I don't find the most appropriate adapter.

Can I do this by this way or I must convert this object into an ArrayList that contains all information and, in fact, use ArrayAdapter for my adapter?

Anyone knows how to do this??

Thanks.

Comment: My first idea was to store the record's information that returns the cursor in an object, the object Customer. I think I should convert it on a ArrayList<String> that contains all information.

Comment: ArrayList<Customer> you can use this..........

Comment: I want to display  one customer's information, it is only one customer. I mean,on the screen, name: name_custormer, lastname: lastname_customer, .... etc... do this on each row of the ListView.But I don't know how to do this... sorry i'm a rookie.

Comment: My answer is down. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your cursor queried you should do something like this

```
String[] from = new String[]{"FirstName"};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.row};

SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cur, from, to);
setListAdapter(sca);
```

check here the documentation for [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).
If you need to do something more complicated with your views you should implement your own custom Cursor adapter:

```
public class ExampleCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ExampleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
        summary.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ExampleDB.KEY_EXAMPLE_SUMMARY)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It can be my solution. But I would ask one question. I throught to display screen by this way.... 1row: Firstname: pepe - 2row: LastName: martínez - 3 row Phone: 6000005555... and show data in this way.... What do you recommmend me that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

And finally, I can find the solution it would be. I'm going to tell you how I did.

I wanted to display details customer by this way:

1. row 1-> Name: name_value
2. row 2-> Last Name: lastname_value
3. row 3-> Phone: phone_value
   ...

N. n row -> n_field: n_value

Fields that describe what value is going to show, i mean "Name:", "Last Name:", "Phone:", ... 
I put all this values on a  *string-array* . I captured that by a  *String []* .

Values, show proper value next the correct field. I put all this inside a ArrayList
and next only have to write the proper adapter:

This Activity inherit *ListActivity*, *ListView* by default.

**SimpleCursorAdapter** is not proper because we have to pass the cursor as argument of this adapter but my Cursor only returns  *only one result, only one record* .

And **CursorAdapter** is refused by the same reason. What can I do next?  **ArrayAdapter** :

```
public class DetalleClienteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private String[] campos_cliente;
    private ArrayList<String> detalles_cliente;


    public DetalleClienteAdapter(Context contexto, int layout, ArrayList<String> detalles)
    {
        super(contexto,layout,detalles);
        //mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);

        // LOS VALORES DE LOS CAMPOS:
        detalles_cliente = detalles;

        // CAMPOS DE DETALLES: nombre, apellidos, etc...
        android.content.res.Resources res = getResources();
        campos_cliente = res.getStringArray(R.array.array_detalle_cliente); 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
        View fila = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalles_cliente, parent, false);

        TextView campo =(TextView)fila.findViewById(R.id.detalles_campo);
        TextView valor =(TextView)fila.findViewById(R.id.detalles_valor);

        campo.setText(campos_cliente[position]);
        valor.setText(detalles_cliente.get(position));

        return fila;

    }

}
```

Now I'm going to write a more efficient adapter, with ViewHolder. What is your opinion about that?

Thanks.